# "he will flip" - What does "flip" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> American A: What is everyones’ opinion about how significant the indictment of Trump organization CFO is?
> American B: Depends on what they have. If the DA shows that he has enough for a conviction...and indicates that he will go for a kill (including Weisellberg's kids)...**he will flip.**

Source: Online forum

What does "he will flip" mean? Usually if you flip a book, you mean to turn the book over. So I guess "he will flip" might mean "he will overthrow it"(Sorry I don't really know how to use the word "overthrow" since I don't know the meaning of "flip").

Comment: You have the right idea: flip (change) from a Trump proponent to an opponent, giving aid to the state prosecuting Trump. That said, this is commonly used slang, informal language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context here is a discussion of a criminal trial, which means we can be fairly certain that the meaning of *flip* is

> 4 : to cause or persuade (a witness) to cooperate in prosecuting a criminal case against an associate

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flip

Comment: You're probably right, but it could also mean "flip out"

Comment: @gotube no not in this context, it's definitely as this answer says.